# How to initialise a class with data which is not available at time of initialisation?

Tags: typescript, design-patterns

I had to write test for this controller class. The controller class' validate function will be called directly or the entry point. This controller uses `SomeService` class'  `doSomethingWithData`. SomeService class needs data which is not available at time of Controller construction, but as validate function's argument.

```
// someservice.ts
class SomeService {
    data: string;

    constructor(data: string) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    doSomethingWithData() {
        // Code to Do something here.
    }
}

// Controller.ts
import SomeService from './someservice.ts';

class MyController {
      validate(event: string) {
           let service = new SomeServce(event);
           service.doSomethingWithData();
      }

}
```

To test it I wanted to use a mock service, so I re-written the controller as :

```
// Controller.ts
import SomeService from './someservice.ts';

class MyController {
      myservice: SomeService = new SomeService(/* Problem: What should I write here, this data would come in future as validate's argument /*);
      validate(event: string) {
           let service = new SomeServce(event);
           service.doSomethingWithData();
      }

}
```

To overcome this, I re-written service's constructor and controller usage

```
 // someservice.ts
class SomeService {
    data: string = '';

    initiateService(data: string) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    doSomethingWithData() {
        // Code to Do something here.
    }
}

// controller.ts
import SomeService from './someservice.ts';

class MyController {
      myservice: SomeService = new SomeService();
      validate(event: string) {
           service.initiate(event);
           service.doSomethingWithData();
      }

}
```

Is there any other way to pass the data to a service which is coming as a function argument? Like in this scenario. Is my temporary solution good enough? Is there any design pattern for this situation?

Comment: Libraries like jest allow you to mock constructors if you're having this problem when writing unit tests.

Comment: Yes! I was facing this problem while writing unit-test with jest. Thank you! for telling this, I wasn't aware of it. And, so I had to re-write constructors to initiate service methods in a lot of services. However, I really wanted to know what is this problem called and how it can be solved.

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem has a name, but I've added an answer which could be one possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to your problem might be using a "factory" method to create `SomeService`. By doing this you can swap out the factory method any time you want to create a different version of `SomeService`.

```
interface SomeService {
    doSomethingWithData: () => void;
}

class MyController {
    constructor(
        public serviceFactory: (event: string) => SomeService
    ) { }

    validate(event: string) {
        const service = this.serviceFactory(event);
        service.doSomethingWithData();
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2FXQG7BLIDeAUMhcgCbobZgAWoA5gOrCMAicYcAXMgAUASmQBeAHzI86YFQDcpAL6lSCADZwAzluQBZAJ4BhdOCjp166CXKUEprWCgBXBGHRRBtypQAOzgCN1QmQtfEIIADFEdygDAUEIPAhwAUcoFlFJNCwccKRvZFFiZBVCvDhgqh4IROTU0KdMmx8fexBHUPyUMWRGYC0AOjCoAiRotw8DOpSwYUVWyhGxiEGaOgh%20kDYOBm5eEQXKFSUgA)